# logistic model interpretation / p-value and its outcome does not make sense

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model

I need a bit of guidance here on a logit regression outcome. From the model I got logit results below [image]
So I thought everything looks good: P value < 0.05 seems to be statistically significant. But once I plot predict vs actual and try to fit the sigmoid -the curvefit was out of iteration and unable to fit the sigmoid - Here's what's it looks like.

[image]

Can anyone help me interpret this model. I'm not sure if I should say this model is good / bad. Look at the chart: obviously it did a very bad job predicting the actual outcome. But from the result why are parameters all significant? What else am I supposed to measure or evaluate the model based on this result?

Comment: your question may be a bit too broad to get good answers. You do appear to have an issue of class imbalance with few predicted probabilities >0.5

Comment: @charles where did see predicted probability > 0.5 sorry I have never at that before. I see my - all I can see is there is no colinearity and p-value > 0.05 so I assume each of this coefficent is siginifican enough to be in the model. I tried to google this but I couldn't understand why would it give me totally off predictive value from the actual. can you help me understand this a bit more ?

Comment: the logistic model outputs a predicted probability from 0 to 1. Based on these values it can then assign a predicted value of 0 or 1 if you want. The blue dots are these probabilities. The brown dots the actual 0 or 1 values. I don't think you can say much from this graph other than you have class imbalance and, at the usual default setting of 0.5 probability, the model will predict all/most values to be 0. (you need to do a VIF test for collinearity and don't think you can get it from output or graph)

Comment: @charles I see, thank you for the explanation. I see what you saying now. I did eliminate the colinear problem from the model. But I guess the issue is I don't have enough success in the dataset ... only 10% of my dataset has success rate. should I redo my model select half success / half non-success and run again ? what should I go from here ?

Comment: I wouldn't read too much into a curve fitting failure -- that happens fairly often.  But how many actual "1"s do you have on is_win?  From the chart the number might be as low as 17, in a sample of 2,306, or just 0.7%.  That would make this a rare-event regression which might require a special approach.  See the work of Gary King, for example.

Comment: If you have 10% successes then something seems off about the plot, which seems to show far fewer successes (as @rolando2 pointed out).

Comment: (1) if you're building a descriptive model a low success rate isn't really an issue. If the success rate is <<10% you might want to consider rare-even regression (I found this interesting: http://christophergandrud.blogspot.com/2012/04/graphing-predicting-legislative.html) (2) if you want a predictive model, this becomes more complicated and I'd repost/change question (I don't have any good answers others might)

Comment: I should add (1) where is the intercept/constant in your model? (2) the pseudo-rsquared is negative? no idea what that means, but might be due to lack of intercept/constant

Comment: @charles I was wondering about the intercept as well, there's no intercept in my result and I have no idea why. I will check out the rare-event regression as suggested. Thank you so much this is very helpful.

Comment: @rolando2 yes , the winning is very low it's 126/2306 to be exact , i should have said < 10% - sorry.

Comment: This is not a plot of predicted vs. actual: it just seems to be an arbitrary set of dot pairs where the x-axis designates a row in a table.  Your problem is that it's next to impossible to learn anything from such an unsuitable graphic. Consider instead something more meaningful, such as (crudely) binning the data by predicted value and plotting the mean observed value against the mean predicted values in the bins. There ought to be a good correspondence--and you can even detect nonlinearity of the (log odds) from such a plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's harder to produce meaningful plots of binary data than it is with continuous data.

One approach is to summarize the data (actual and predicted) into one way and / or multi-way combinations of independent variable categories (binning continuous independent variables), and ploting these summary rates.  Sometimes I find it helps to shade results by the number of observations in each cell/bin so that the result looks more "dense" where there are more observations, compensating for the fact that you can't plot individual points, and not all combinations neccessarily have equal numbers of observations.

For example, you could summarise the actual and predicted rates by your `ASS` variable, and then plot actual and predicted rates of each `ASS` category on the horizontal axis.  (If `ASS` is continuous you will need to bin the data first).

As a second example you could group the data by all combinations (binning continuous variables as needed), summarize for every cell, and then plot predicted rates for each cell (on a vertical axis) against actual rates for each cell (on the horizontal).  This should resemble a scatter plot.  You can also plot residuals.

Thirdly, you can summarize by combinations of variables and then plot actual rates or residual rates (vertically) against an independent variable (horizontally).  Depending on how many cells you have and the effects of binning, you can plot actual rates either as points (possibly using different colors for different values of other independent variables), or in a box and whisker style chart.  These can be quite helpful at identifying interaction effects, correlation between "independent" variables, and/or heteroskedasticity.

How useful these graphs are depends on the data and how you choose combinations of variables to summarize the data by, and the choice of bins of any continuous variables affects the results greatly.  It can be a lot of work summarizing and binning data and caculating predicted rates for each cell and graphic against various dimensions, but the results can (sometimes) provide a lot of intuition into the data.